# SQL server RANK () usages

Tags: sql-server

I've been summarizing for myself - the window functions in SQL server.

But it's also very important for me - no just to know *how* to write functions  , but also - in *what* scenarios should I use them.

Well I can honestly say I don't have an answer for this for the `Rank` function where it is perfectly clear in what scenarios I should use `DENSE_RANK` :

Example : there are `5` competitors and `2` of them finished the end line at the same time - so both get same rank (  with DENSE_RANK)- both will get `1`. The other `3` competitors (that finished also the same time) would get rank `2` ( etc...)

**Question:**

In what scenarios should I use the `Rank`  function , I know how numbers are generated but I don't see any scenario for using it

Visualization example :

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(NAME NVARCHAR(MAX),val money)

insert INTO @t SELECT 'a',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'a',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'a',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'a',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'b',200
insert INTO @t SELECT 'b',200
insert INTO @t SELECT 'd',400
insert INTO @t SELECT 'e',500
insert INTO @t SELECT 'f',600
select  Name,
        val,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME  ORDER BY name),
        val/ SUM(val) OVER(PARTITION BY NAME )  AS '1AgainstTotalHimself',
        val/ SUM(val) OVER( )  AS '1AgainstOthers' , 
        NTILE(2) OVER ( PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY name) AS 'ntile2' ,
        NTILE(2) OVER ( ORDER BY name) AS 'ntile' , -- ( 9%2=1  , so group #1 will get more number) 
        RANK( ) OVER ( ORDER BY name  ) AS  Rank,
        DENSE_RANK( ) OVER (ORDER BY name) AS DENSERANK

from @t
```

[image]

Comment: in your scenario `RANK` would answer the question - how many competitors finished ahead of each competitor

Comment: Rank is pretty commonly used.  In your example, 4 tied for first place (taking up positions 1-4), The next available spot is number 5.

Comment: @bowlturner You're describing the visualization into words which is same same... As I said - I know how numbers are generated and why 5 is the value. but for which task (that my boss give me ), I should think about RANK ?

Comment: yes it's used in things all the time.  http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/worldbuilding.stackexchange.com  this is the stack exchange using it.

Comment: @bowlturner No. this is DENSE RANK look here : http://i.imgur.com/FPfsVNv.png . my question is about RANK not DENSERANK

Comment: Did you see what comes after #4?  #10  you stopped one number too soon.

Comment: @bowlturner Yes. you're right. apologies. but what does it mean the 10 after 4 ? in human task... I mean why not shoding 5 after 4 ?

Comment: It means those tied at #10 have 9 individual people ahead of them,

Comment: @bowlturner It's weird. in denserank I can look at `2` and say : well I know it belongs to group #2 , so he is second  at something. but with RANK - looking at 7 ( in my question pic) - I can say nothing about this 7.

Comment: it all depends on what you need to do with the information.  In tournaments, if the first 10 places get a cash prize, and 3 people tie for 2nd, they take 2,3,4 place money and split it equally, and the next person gets the 5th place prize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with Aaron Bertrand - I finally got the "human worded description" for when to use Rank :

> `dense_rank()` is when 4 people tied for first, the next-best is in
>   second. `rank()` is when 4 people tied for first, the next-best if
>   fifth. There isn't really any technical reason you would use one over
>   the other, it's how you want the numbers displayed and consumed. In
>   some sports, for example, they want a nice clean 1st, 2nd, 3rd. **In
>   others, they want your rank to reflect(!!!) how many people finished ahead(!!!)
>   of you** (well, minus one, depending on your perspective).

So with Rank , I dont care about being at first place or second place in a 1,2,3 world" - It is more competitive :  the number itself represents also the weight of being second.( for example)

so if 100 people win at 05:00 and i'm after them at 05:01 - then they all will be first place in DenseRank ( and i'll be at second place). but with Rank - they all be 1 and I'll be 101. so it's adding a "weight" of being second.

Also , now  I see where the word *dense* comes from. it's removing the "weight"
.

Another interpretation :

- With dense_rank :  looking at 2 , doesn't mean i'm almost the best. there could be 100 people who finished at 05:00
- With rank : looking at 2 , means truly i'm almost the best.

Comment: I think the "dense" comes from not having any gaps in the final rankings. There is one (or more) 1s, one or more 2s, one or more 3s, etc. With `RANK()`, you'd have 1, 5, 6, ... in your example. So missing numbers: 2, 3, 4, ...

Answer (score 3):

`RANK()` can be seen as an equivalent of `TOP (n) WITH TIES`, except the latter will get you the specified rows over the entire set only while the former can also do so over partitions.

So, if you needed to select, say, top five results per group but include all rows, if any, that tied with the #5 row in each group, `RANK()` would solve this for you:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    DepartmentID,
    Salary,
    rnk = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DepartmentID ORDER BY Salary DESC)
  FROM
    dbo.Employee
)
SELECT
  EmployeeID,
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  DepartmentID,
  Salary
FROM
  ranked
WHERE
  rnk <= 5
;
```

Comment: it seems pretty weird to mention scalar which would be used as a filter because adding 2 more rows and I dont have 5. I think it's more to tell about one as a perspective to it's previouses ( how many previouses). see here http://i.imgur.com/3OdIYYQ.png

Comment: Absence of number 5 in the rankings doesn't change the fact that RANK is an equivalent of TOP WITH TIES. The `rnk <= 5` condition would still give you top 5 plus ties.